# How to send dynamic parameters in url of sharepoint modal dialog options

Tags: development, jquery, modal-dialog

I have the following code for the javascript modal popup.

```
function ShowSearchBox() {
var options = {
    title: "Search Here",
    width: 760,
    height: 380,
    url: "/_layouts/CustomSearch/SearchPage/Searchpage.aspx"
};
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

}

This is working fine. But now i want to send parameters to the url like, `"/_layouts/CustomSearch/SearchPage/Searchpage.aspx?TableName=tblName &columnName=colName"`

Here tblName and colName are not the static one. those are property values. We will set at the time of deploying the webpart. So these two values should be like dynamic parameters. we should insert the variables here instead of static values? How to pass here like this.
I am calling `ShowSearchBox()` function in the `'.js'` file when ever a button is clicked like below.
`$("#btnShowDialog").click(function (e) {
        ShowSearchBox();
        e.preventDefault();
    });`

How to achieve it? I searched but didn't find correct solution. This [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29866/open-modal-dialog-from-code-behind-with-parameters) is some what similar but i am not able to understand

Answer (score 1):

I think one solution for this is to do the following:

1. Do not place the ShowSearchBox function in a separate .js file, but leave it in the aspx file.
2. Add two parameters to the function, just to make it nicer: `$("#btnShowDialog").click(function (e) { **ShowSearchBox(tableName,columnName)**; e.preventDefault(); });`
3. Add before the `$(document).ready(...)` part the following

   ```
   var tableName = '<%=this.TableName %>';
   var columnName = '<%=this.ColumnName %>';
   ```

   `TableName` and `ColumnName` are properties in the code behind of the aspx page. On their `get {...}` branch you can retrieve the values dynamically. Then the values are insterted into the generated HTML and if you do a view source of the page in a browser, you will see something like this

   ```
   var tableName = 'table1';
   var columnName = 'column1';
   ```

   You can use these global javascript variables in the rest of your javascript code.

I hope it helped.

Comment: Yeah I also tried with as this.

Comment: And, didn't it solve your problem? If not, please tell me why not, so maybe I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. Why don't you do it exactly like you said?

```
function ShowSearchBox(var) {
    var options = {
        title: "Search Here",
        width: 760,
        height: 380,
        url: "/_layouts/CustomSearch/SearchPage/Searchpage.aspx?Foo=" + var
    }
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}

$("#btnShowDialog").click(function (e) { ShowSearchBox('myValue'); e.preventDefault(); });
```

On searchpage.aspx, you can get the variable easily with Request.QueryString:

```
string foo = (string)Request.QueryString["Foo"]
```

Comment: In the example you given the parameter `myvalue` is static one. But This should not be static. It is dynamic value. Thats why I struck. I clearly mentioned that those are property values in C#. I know how to achieve this with static values brother.

Comment: But you can fill in those values from your webpart. When you are creating your button, you can set the OnClientClick property and reference your property there. If the button isn't your own button and you can't set the property, you can still pass any variable you want to your own javascript function. For example, in the rendercontents method: html.Write("<script>$(document).ready(function(){MyFunction(\"" + myValue + "\");});</script>"); Then you can attach the click event from inside your javascript file, using your own value.