# How delete a record from list by using a jQuery

Tags: 2010, development, jquery

I find aut a this article about to easy and fast delete a records from list: http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/245147 How could I use it ? Can I use it on cs files, if yes so how can I use it ? Where should it be written ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about SPServices, but here is the method I am using to delete a record from a list.

```
function DeleteRecordFromList(listName,recordId){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/'+listName+'('+recordId+')',
    type: "DELETE",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function () {
        alert("Record has been deleted");
    },

    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
    }
  });
}
```

Be careful, the list name is case sensitive! 
If you want to do it from C#, you have instantiate an HttpRequest and call the same url as in the ajax call above. But if you are already in C#, why not just use the Object Model? Why to use jQuery?
More about listdata.svc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx

I hope it helped!

Comment: +1 "But if you are already in C#, why not just use the Object Model?"

Comment: But how Use It. I must send a IDis from C# by the Hiddenfield, or somthing better ?

Comment: Can it be do from Event Receiver ?

Comment: Well, you could use a global javascript variable like: var ID = '<%= IdPropertyFromCodeBehind%>'; See [this] (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52713/how-to-send-dynamic-parameters-in-url-of-sharepoint-modal-dialog-options/52745#52745) post too, maybe.

Comment: Or send the ID in a QueryString parameter... No, I don't think an event receiver is an answer to the problem, the way you presented it. Are there other circumstances to consider?

Comment: Yes, when i Creating a Record in FirstList, I must creating a lot of records in secound list bonded with created record in first list from date Start to date END So in delete cascade i must delete only one record in  First List, and a lot of record in second list, One record are created in secound lists, are in one day.

Comment: A Po Polsku, tak jest trochę namotane, gdyż gdy tworzę record w pierwszej liście to wtedy w drugiej liście jest tworzone dużo rekordów, każdy innego następnego dnia w zakresie od daty początkowej do daty końcowej. I każdy rekord w tej drugiej liście jest koleejnym dniem od daty Start do daty stop. Dlatego chcąc skasować Kaskadowo muszę skasować jeden rekord z pierwszej listy i wszystkie powiązane z drugiej, a ponieważ w items Adding nie mam ostatniego elementu to mi brakuje jednego rekordu by skasować. Znów przy items Added nie pracuje mi wszystko za dobrze.

Comment: Ok, so if I understood you correctly: you want to cascade delete items from the SecondList when you delete an item from the First list. In this case, please consider adding an extra column to the SecondList to hold the ID of the "parent" from the FirstList. Add an EventReceiver on ItemDeleting on the FirstList, and delete all items also from SecondList where secondListItem["ParentId"] == idBeingDeleted.

Answer (score 1):

I am not repeating the steps for jQuery as it's already described by @Norbert, but you can have a look at this [post](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2011/06/delete-list-item-using-web-service.html) for C# way